# PR of zero with lots of inbound links

Tags: seo, pagerank

I run http://Fanfootage.com which has a PageRank of 0 and has been online for over 1 year. A few months ago, we moved from another domain name to this, and also switched to using all https.

We do not do any magic/shady tricks. I got nofollows set up, unique page titles, good descriptions, h1 tags in place, all links work across site, etc.

Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before anything else i want to start of with 1 tip.
Don't focus too much on PageRank.

PageRank is something that is invisible to anyone else than Google itself. They do give us a very basic indicator with the PageRank toolbar. But this is only updated every couple of months and until quite recently it hadn't been updated in over a year.

That being said.

I do not see anything wrong with your website. You did mention that you switched domains a couple of months ago. Since Google rarely updates it's PageRank toolbar i think that this could be the problem.

**Some resources on PageRank**

- [Is PageRank finally dead?](http://searchengineland.com/is-pagerank-finally-dead-it-seems-to-be-at-least-in-the-google-toolbar-170861)
- [PageRank Toolbar update December 2013](http://gplusgeek.com/google-page-rank-toolbar-update-december-2013/)
- [Agent Rank and PageRank](http://www.realsmo.com/2014/03/agent-rank-is-here.html)

Comment: Interesting, did not know that it was not real-time. So this is the history of updates: http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/google-pr-update/ ?

Comment: Yes, it is. But the PageRank toolbar doesn't give us a very good view of our websites actual PageRank.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a little check on your domain pagerank its supposed to have a Pagerank of 2.2.

See the details here:
http://siteexplorer.info/domain/fanfootage.com

Unfortunately in pagerank toolbar your domain still show Pagerank of zero. I believe there is some thing missing on your domain or site setting. I would advise to check it via [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/).